# C++11 vector holding 2 different subclasses, but not at the same time

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

Suppose I have a base class `Base`, two subclasses `A` and `B`, with the latter having itself a subclass `C`.

I would like to enforce by design that an `std::vector` can hold objects of either types (subclasses like `C` included), but only one type at a time -- that is, either I have a vector of `A`s, or a vector of `B`s and `C`s.

Is it possible to have this in C++11 (of course, I could enforce this constraint when adding elements to the vector, but I wonder if I could prevent this via a clever design)? How can I structure the class hierarchy to obtain this?

Thanks in advance for your help!

R.

Comment: By "one type at a time", do you mean that the same "vector" could be switched between types at runtime by emptying it and filling it with new objects of another type?

Comment: How large are your elements (sizeof(A), sizeof(B), sizeof(C))? Because if sizeof(C) > sizeof(B), this is only possible by indirection (storing *pointers* to instances of B/C), then a `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base>>` would do, you just need to make sure that all elements are of the same type. Otherwise you would need something like a `union`, since `std::variant` isn't available yet.

Comment: Yes, I mean that if I start filling the vector with elements of type A, I shouldn't be allowed to push Bs and Cs, and the same in the other sense. Of course, smart pointers are allowed if needed.

Comment: @RH6 How do you choose if you are only going to fill `A` or `B`? And what do you do with these vectors? Looking at your comment on one of the answer, it looks like you choose at compile time (MacOS vs. Unix compilation)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`boost::variant< std::vector<A>, std::vector<boost::variant<B,C>> >` describes your structure.

In C++17, replaced `boost::` with `std::`.  The two are very similar, but not identical.

If you cannot use `boost`, you'll have to basically write a `variant` of your own.

Use is a bit awkward, but so are your type restrictions.  Use gets easier in C++14 with auto-lambdas (which I believe boost variant visitor supports).

In C++14/17 you might do something like (pseudocode)

```
template<class F, class T, class=std::enable_if_t<!is_variant<T>{}>>
decltype(auto) visit( F&& f, T&& t ) {
  return std::forward<F>(f)(std::forward<T>(t));
}
my_special_vec v;

visit( [&](auto&& v){
  for (auto&& e:v) {
    Base* b = visit( [&](auto&& e){
      e.do_operation();
      return std::addressof(e);
    }, decltype(e)(e));
    b->do_virtual_operation();
  }
}, v );
```

which should non-virtually call `e.do_operation()` on whichever of `A`, `B` or `C` your vector contains, then call `do_virtual_operation()` on the instance as a `Base`.

And this is the easier, C++14 version.  The C++11 version gets awkward with function objects and other mess.

Answer (score 1):

`std::vector<T>` can only ever hold one type of object: `T`. It can never hold derived objects, or change the type at runtime.

By using indirection, you could allocate the objects separately, and instead store pointers to base class in the vector. This allows the vector to point to derived objects, but it doesn't prevent mixing different types at the same time.

You can achieve what you describe quite closely with a tagged union. C++11 standard library doesn't have a tagged union type (`std::variant` is to be introduced in C++17), so you need to implement it yourself (or you can of course use a third party implementation as always). A tagged union allows you to list types that can be stored, and one type is active at a time. So you could have a variant of `std::vector<A>`, `std::vector<A>` and `std::vector<C>`.

That said, you have not described why you would need this and a better design might be to use a few separate vectors instead.

Comment: I have two subclasses representing closely related items that have to implement the same interface, but whose usage is in mutual exclusion -- like SoftwareForMacOS and SoftwareForLinux -- and a vector that has to group them (representing, in the example, those installed on my PC). My idea was to enforce by construction that, once a SoftwareForLinux is pushed in the vector, no SoftwareForMacOS can be pushed in the same vector.

Comment: @RH6 what should be the behaviour of adding an object of wrong type?